# What is mean by 'cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful' in Smoothing spline in R?

Tags: r, statistics, spline, smoothing, cross-validation

I am using smoothing spline function in R but I get a warning message saying:

```
  > boneMaleSmooth = smooth.spline( bone[males,"age"], bone[males,"spnbmd"], cv=TRUE)
    Warning message:
    In smooth.spline(bone[males, "age"], bone[males, "spnbmd"], cv = TRUE) :
    cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful

  > boneFemaleSmooth = smooth.spline( bone[females,"age"], bone[females,"spnbmd"], cv=TRUE)
    Warning message:
    In smooth.spline(bone[females, "age"], bone[females, "spnbmd"],  :
    cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful
```

I read it somewhere saying it does not matter much. But I am not sure what caused it. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you have some data points that share an x-value. It shouldn't make too much of a difference to the practical result you get in most cases. However, using `cv=F` is a better way to do things with such data.

The reason behind it is in the smooth.spline code, it works out the total number of x-values:

```
n <- length(x)
```

And then it starts to process your data (I've included comments):

```
xx <- round((x - mean(x))/tol) #normalise the data
nd <- !duplicated(xx) #get rid of duplicated x values! THIS IS PART OF THE WARNING
ux <- sort(x[nd]) #Sort the data
nx <- length(ux) $Get the length of processed data to work with
```

Then, later, the warning is thrown if nx < n:

```
if (CV && nx < n) #CV is based on the input parameter `cv`
        warning("cross-validation with non-unique 'x' values seems doubtful")
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting 'cv=TRUE' as you have done uses "ordinary" cross validation which uses a leave-one-out type strategy for validation. This strategy isn't as useful when you have duplicated `x` values.

When you have duplicated `x` values, it's recommended to use `cv=FALSE` to trigger the "generalized" cross-validation. See the discussion in `?smooth.spline`

Answer (score 1):

Does your `bone[males,"age"]` vector contain duplicate values? If so I think this is the source of the warning. `smooth.spline` tries to determine an optimal smoothing smoothing parameter by leave one out cross-validation. Leave one out cv is a bit of a strange thing to do when the things you are leaving out have duplicates, so it's issuing a warning.

See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html for details.

A way to avoid this is to specify your own value of `spar` in the call to `smooth.spline`, and tweak it until you get something that makes sense to you. The leave one out cross-validation probably won't cause problems in most cases. Another way, maybe, to avoid the warning is to slightly jitter your x-values.

Update:
Per the answer of @MrFlick, using generalized cross-validation (cv = FALSE) seems to be recommended in the help file. The statement is somewhat opaque:

> The ‘generalized’ cross-validation method will work correctly when
>   there are duplicated points in x. However, it is ambiguous what
>   leave-one-out cross-validation means with duplicated points, and the
>   internal code uses an approximation that involves leaving out groups
>   of duplicated points. cv = TRUE is best avoided in that case.